# clojure: with-redefs doesn't work with clojure.core functions?

Tags: clojure

I've a question about `with-redefs`. The following example doesn't work as expected.
In `findmax`, `clojure.core/max` is always called instead of the anonymous function in the
`with-redefs` statement.

```
(defn findmax [x y]
  (max x y))

(with-redefs (clojure.core/max (fn [x y] (- x y)))
  (findmax 2 5))
```

When I make the following changes everything works as expected:

```
(defn mymax [x y]
  (max x y))

(defn findmax [x y]
  (mymax x y))

(with-redefs (my/max (fn [x y] (- x y)))
  (findmax 2 5))
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`max` is inlined by the Clojure compiler for arities greater than 1, so there is no reference to the Var `#'clojure.core/max` in the compiled code and no way to change the behaviour of code fragments that use `#'max` by changing its root binding. For arity 1, this does not happen:

```
(defn my-max [& args] :foo)

(with-redefs [clojure.core/max my-max] (max 0))
;= :foo
(with-redefs [clojure.core/max my-max] (max 0 1))
;= 1
(with-redefs [clojure.core/max my-max] (max 0 1 2))
;= 2

;; and so on
```

This is controlled by the entries at keys `:inline` and `:inline-arities` in the source of `max`; see `(source max)`.

There are quite a few automatically inlined functions in `clojure.core` -- mostly the simple arithmetic operations. Client code is free to define new ones (by attaching explicit `:inline` and possibly `:inline-arities` metadata or by using `definline`). The expected effect is similar to defining a macro, except an inlined function is still available for higher-order usage. It's important to note that the current implementation has its surprises (see [CLJ-1227](http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJ-1227) in the Clojure JIRA, for example, and the more recent issues linked therefrom), so at the end of the day, for client code, careful use of regular macros and companion functions is likely to be preferable for the time being. In the future, inlined functions may well be replaced by regular functions paired with compiler macros -- this is the ClojureScript model.